# Limit cart to products only from the same category

Tags: cart

Could it be possible to throw an exception flag if a user tried to add products that are not in the same category as the items already in their cart?  Much the same way that Magento throws a flag if a user tries to add both a Nominal and Regular product to the same cart.

Answer (score 1):

I have written the sample code, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345619/magento-limit-3-products-from-category-per-order) is the actual answer that will work for you:

Create an observer for event `checkout_cart_product_add_after`

```
<events>
        <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <observers>
                <enableduplicateproductstatus>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>limitcartproductbycategory/observer</class>
                    <method>cartlimit</method>
                </enableduplicateproductstatus>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    </events>
```

Create:

> app/code/local/MagePal/LimitCartProductByCategory/Model/Observer.php

```
class MagePal_LimitCartProductByCategory_Model_Observer 
{

    public function cartlimit(Varien_Event_Observer  $observer)
    {
        $category_ids = array();

        $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        foreach($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item){
              $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getId());
              $product_category_ids = explode(",", $product->getCategoryIds());
              //$product_category_ids = $product->getCategoryIds();

              array_push($category_ids, $product_category_ids);
        }

        $justAdded = $observer->getQuoteItem();


        $productJustAdded = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($justAdded->getId());

        //total the category id in $category_ids
        //if $productJustAdded->getCategoryIds exist in $category_ids, 
        //then check to see if category id count greater than 3
        // if true then add error msg and try setting the qty to 0

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this complete code? I tried and its not working